# Вычитание процента

Tags: php

Подскажите есть простой код который может вычитать проценты из суммы, есть 2 переменных

```
$proc = "1";
$mon = "560";
```

$proc = это проценты, $mon = это сумма из которой вычитать

Comment: «Есть»

Вы с какого класса школы перестали на математику ходить? Сколько будет 1% от 560?

Comment: Скидка будет 5.6 руб, но мне нужно что бы код вычислял

Comment: `$skidka = $mon * $proc / 100;`

`$itog = $mon - $skidka`

что у вас не получалось?

Comment: Ну кто так считает? Очевидно же, что умножение будет работать быстрее, чем деление.

    $skidka = $mon * $proc * 0.01;

Comment: @Равнодушный хотите окончательно сбить с толку ТС? =)

Comment: >хотите окончательно сбить с толку ТС? =)

@sergiks человека, который испытывает проблемы с математикой 4 класса? трудно сбить с толку ещё боше, чем это уже есть

Comment: @DreamChild, на Хэшкоде, вроде бы, отсутствует декларированный минимальный уровень знаний. Думаю, тут надо помогать, при желании, на уровне спрашивающего. Спрашивает как ребёнок – объяснить как ребёнку: просто и терпеливо.

Comment: @sergiks разве я где-то утверждал, что помогать не нужно? Речь была немного о другом

Answer (score 3):

```
function percentage($amount, $perc)
{
return $amount * $perc / 100;
}

function discount($amount, $perc)
{
 return percentage($amount, 100-$perc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну дак в чем проблема то? $mon*$proc/100